# CakePHP Index with query

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm building a prototype search application using CakePHP and I have a search controller that has the following code so far:

```
class SearchController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'Search';

    var $uses = array();

    function index ( $query )
    {
        $query = $_GET['q'];

        $this->set('title_for_layout', $query. ' &ndash; smplr');

        // if no query then redirect to home
        if ( !$query )
        {
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
}
```

So this would be fired when a user has something like this: `domain.com/search?q=Hello`

My question is how to use the query passed into `index()` ?

At the moment I have to manually create a new variable to grab the query string using `$_GET` which I'm sure is NOT the way to do this using Cake.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: thanks, buddy. have fun with your caaaaaake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$this->params['url']['q'];
```

More specifically:

```
function index ( $query )
    {
        $query = $this->params['url']['q'];

....
```

Comment: So I wouldn't need the `$query` inside the `index()` at all then? As I could just use the variable content straight from the params?

Comment: Yes, you wouldn't need to catch $query as a function argument.

Comment: Why not though? When dealing with normal functions like creating, editing etc you would do. Thanks

Comment: Because you're not passing it the normal way. Your url is: domain.com/search?q=asdf. To catch it how you want to, your url should be: domain.com/search/index/asdf

Comment: What's the difference between `$query = $this->params['url']['q'];` and `$query = $_GET['q'];`

Comment: $_GET is native php, and $this->params['url'] is provided from cake. It's likely they've already scrubbed it for security purposes, as opposed to you pulling it right out of $_GET which is raw from the user. Did I earn your acceptance of my answer yet? :)